# divide custom field values in div every two values

Tags: php, custom-field, loop, count, plugins

i have this html mark-up to sort some data

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <img src="images/member-schools/ms1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <h4>American International School - East</h4>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <img src="images/member-schools/ms2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <h4>Dover American International School</h4>
</div>
```

and i am pulling out the data from repeatable group metabox i use from [CMB2](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2/wiki/Field-Types#group)

this is the code for the registered metabox

```
function schools() {

// Start with an underscore to hide fields from custom fields list
$prefix = 'schools_';

/**
 * Repeatable Field Groups
 */
$schools= new_cmb2_box( array(
    'id'           => $prefix . 'metabox',
    'title'        => __( 'schools', 'cmb2' ),
    'object_types' => array( 'page', ),
    'show_on'      => array( 'key' => 'id', 'value' => 6 ),
    'closed'     => true,
) );

$group_field_id = $schools->add_field( array(
    'id'          => $prefix . 'field',
    'type'        => 'group',
    'options'     => array(
        'group_title'   => __( 'Slide {#}', 'cmb2' ), // {#} gets replaced by row number
        'add_button'    => __( 'Add Another Slide', 'cmb2' ),
        'remove_button' => __( 'Remove Slide', 'cmb2' ),
        'sortable'      => true, // beta
    ),
) );


$schools->add_group_field( $group_field_id, array(
    'name' => __( 'Photo', 'cmb2' ),
    'id'   => 'photo',
    'type' => 'file',
) );

$schools->add_group_field( $group_field_id, array(
    'name' => __( 'Name', 'cmb2' ),
    'id'   => 'name',
    'type' => 'text',
) );}
```

i pull the data out through this code

```
$schools = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'schools_field', true );
```

where $schools is an array that contain an image and title for each entry which i can loop through to pull out the values.
my question is how i can add `<div class="row">` every two items from that array , because i need a row for each two entries

EDIT: var_dump result

```
array(3) {
    [0] => array(3) {
        ["photo_id"]    => string(2) "89"
        ["photo"]       => string(56) "http://localhost/NCSR/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/ms3.jpg"
        ["name"]        => string(8) "School 1" 
    }
    [1] => array(3) {
        ["photo_id"]    => string(2) "88"
        ["photo"]       => string(56) "http://localhost/NCSR/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/ms2.jpg"
        ["name"]        => string(8) "school 2"
    }
    [2] => array(3) {
        ["photo_id"]    => string(2) "87"
        ["photo"]       => string(56) "http://localhost/NCSR/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/ms1.jpg"
        ["name"]        => string(8) "school 3"
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please post structure of the array $schools. A `var_dump($schools)` will be great.

Comment: edited the code to add the metabox structure

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but I would like you to please post the result of `var_dump($schools)` for me to quickly answer your question.

Comment: edited the post to inculde vardumb result , i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way to do this , turned out to be kind of easy here is what i did

```
$Aschools = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'american_member_schools_field', true );

$i = 0;

$entries = count($Aschools);

foreach ( (array) $Aschools as $key => $Aschool ) {

  $logo = $Aname = '';

  $i++;


  if ( isset( $Aschool['name'] ) )
      $Aname =  $Aschool['name'] ;

  if ( isset( $Aschool['logo_id'] ) ) {
      $logo = wp_get_attachment_image( $Aschool['logo_id'], 'full', null, array(
          'class' => 'img-responsive',
      ) );
  }

  // Do something with the data

  if ($i & 1) {
    echo '<div class="row row-eq-height">';
    echo '<div class="col-xs-2">';
    echo $logo;
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="col-xs-4">';
    echo '<h4>' . $Aname . '</h4>';
    echo '</div>';
  } elseif ($i & 1 && $i == $entries) {
    echo '<div class="row row-eq-height">';
    echo '<div class="col-xs-2">';
    echo $logo;
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="col-xs-4">';
    echo '<h4>' . $Aname . '</h4>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
  } else {
    echo '<div class="col-xs-2">';
    echo $logo;
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="col-xs-4">';
    echo '<h4>' . $Aname . '</h4>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
display_schools($string);

function display_schools($string) {
    $counter = 0;
    $i = 0;
    $len = count($string);
    foreach($string as $school) {
        if($counter == 0) {
            echo '<div class="row">';
        }
        ?>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <img src="<?php echo $school['photo']; ?>" class="img-responsive photo_id_<?php echo $school['photo_id']; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <h4><?php echo $school['name']; ?></h4>
            </div>
        <?php
        if($counter == 1 || $i == $len - 1) {
            echo '</div>';
            $counter = 0;
        } else {
            $counter = $counter + 1;    
        }

        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice logic i like the way you did it , much cleaner code than my answer and practical to use on other templates , i will give it a try , i will appreciate it if you can tell me what do you think about my answer , is there something i am missing or did not think about ?

Comment: I've not fully analyzed your code actually. But, I see 2 problems when skimmed through. Number 1: iterator `$i` is normally updated just before the loop ends. Number 2: You should be displaying rows when `$i` is even. So the condition for it should be `if(!($i & 1))`. I've not fully reviewed your code.